# Nested Object.keys() are printing properties multiple times instead of only once

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects that I need to loop through so I can use their properties later on. However if I print the variables each of them is printed twice. I understand that because I have the `Object.keys()` inside other `Object.keys()`. Is there any way to loop through these two objects and only get each variable one time?

My code:

```
Object.keys(newData.name).map(async key => {
    Object.keys(newData._temp.images).map(async keyImage => {
        console.log(newData.name[key].name,'printed 2x instead of once');
        console.log(newData._temp.images[keyImage].rawFile.preview, 'printed 2x instead of once');
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you callbacks async?

Comment: @AntonRusak Im using await request to back-end, its not relevant to this.

Comment: could you give an example of `newData` and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic here of nesting the loops is wrong.

these 2 object does not seem to be connected to one another, meaning you do not need the data from the first loop in order to perform the other loops. just split it into 2 seperate loops, would save you both time and repititions:

```
let nameKeys = Object.keys(newData.name).map(key => newData.name[key].name);
let imagesKeys = Object.keys(newData._temp.images).map(keyImage => 
                 newData._temp.images[keyImage].rawFile.preview);
```

now you can access `nameKeys` and `imageKeys` whenever you want, and they will contain the values you previously logged. My naming might be a bit off tho, feel free to change that :D

Also, as others mentioned- no need for the `async` keyword... you do not perform any async operation inside (yet, at least. if thats what you're planning then go ahead and keep it).

Comment: The issue I have though is that I need these values to use later. So I need them to be accessable. This way they are not accessable.

Comment: @AdamSulc aaand... why not? if instead of the `console.log` you save the value from each iteration into an array / object / w.e you want - they will be accessible. I'll edit answer to reflect that

Comment: This makes the valus accessible, however there is one more issue. I am creating an object with these values: `var objectToCreate = { name: nameKeys, image: imagesKeys };`. Right now the keys have an array as their values. I need them to be just strings. I hope thats somewhat clear.

Comment: well, I know the `nameKeys` and `imagesKeys` are now arrays with the values you wanted. But you say you want them as strings... well you can `JSON.stringify` the arrays, is that what you need? or else i'd need more explanation about how exactly you want the final object to look like, or how do you want to group the bunch of values you just grabbed into a string

Comment: if its complicated to explain here let me know i'll open us a private chat window so I can better help from there :)

Comment: I eventually managed to solve this based on you answer and comments, thanks

Answer (score 0):

These iterators do not need to be nested. The second iterator is not looping through an item of the first iterator.

```js
Object.keys(newData.name).forEach(key => {
    console.log(newData.name[key].name);
});
Object.keys(newData._temp.images).forEach(keyImage => {
    console.log(keyImage[keyImage].rawFile.preview);
});
```

If you are only iterested in outputting data, then `.map()` is not the right function to use because this is used when you care about the return value. Use `.forEach()` if you just want to loop through things.

Also, the `async` keyword is not needed here.. unless you plan to do some async/await stuff in the loops later!

Comment: The issue I have though is that I need these values to use later. So I need them to be accessable. This way they are not accessable.

Comment: In that case, can you provide a more comprehensive description of the problem? So that we can get a better picture of what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

You could iterate over the indices once and then access the values in both arrays:

```
 const names = Object.keys(newData.name);
 const images = Object.keys(newData._temp.images);

for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(names.length, images.length); i++) {
  const name = names[i];
  const image = images[i];
  //...
}
```

Comment: that would only give him the first `Math.min(names.length, images.length)`, would totally miss properties if they do not have the same number of properties...

Comment: They should be treated as separate entities. This couples them unnecessarily.